# Не работает if в телеграм-боте

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Помогите пожалуйста! Я пишу бота на питоне через библиотеку telebot, и  столкнулся с проблемой. У меня есть таблица, в которой присутствует переменная mode, и я хотел бы сделать так, чтобы если mode == 2 то мы получали сообщение от бота дальше

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text']) 
def test_msg(message):
    for mode in sql.execute(f'SELECT mode FROM modes WHERE user_id = {user_id}'):
        if mode =='2':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'test message')
        else:
             if mode < '2':
                bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, 'url')
```

Проблема в том, что бот видит эту переменную но не реагирует на ее значение

Comment: И вас абсолютно не смущает что вы в одном случае сравниваете с числом, а в другом со строкой?

Comment: Извините ошибся

Comment: Нужно просто понимать, что 2 не равно "2". Их в питоне и сравнить-то напрямую не получится.

Comment: А что делать тогда?

Comment: чему равен `mode`?

Comment: mode это регистор точки последнего сохранения действия игрока в боте в данный момент он равен 2

Comment: в коде не хватает одной закрывающей скобки

Comment: Не подскажете где именно?

Answer (score 1):

Я не совсем понял что вы хотели написать но вот возможно правильный вариант:

```
if int(mode) == 2:
   bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'test message') 
else:
    if int(mode) < 2:
       bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, 'url')
```

Также можно сократить все с помощю elif вот пример:

```
if int(mode) == 2:
   bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'test message') 
elif int(mode) < 2:
   bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, 'url')
```

Comment: Простите, но он все равно не работает

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
for mode in sql.execute(f'SELECT mode FROM modes WHERE user_id = {user_id}').fetchall():
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: К сожалению и это не помогло

Comment: Сделайте принт `mode` и покажите что выдает

Comment: Сделано выдает значение которое храниться в этой функции

Comment: то бишь строка `2`?

Comment: Да вы правы выдает значение 2

Comment: Так а что не помогло то? Вы к инту привели его?